# Create Google Calendar Event with URL and predefined Event Id

Tags: google-calendar-api

I would like to create a Google Calendar event with a URL having a predefined eventId, so that if user want to modify the event later I can redirect him to the Event using predefined eventId stored in database.

Comment: What is your question? If I understand you correctly, you want to create an event for which you set the event ID. Did you try doing this? If that's the case, what issues did you encounter? Do you have any code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `events.insert` method as specified there: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

You can pass a custom Id on the `requestBody` of your query that you can use later, alongside your **calendarId**, to edit your event through the `update` or `patch` method.

Follow the guidelines when generating your custom Id:

> Provided IDs must follow these rules:
>
> - characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in
>   RFC2938
> - the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
> - the ID must be unique per calendar
> - Due to the globally distributed nature of the system, we cannot guarantee that ID collisions will be detected at event creation time.
>   To minimize the risk of collisions we recommend using an established
>   UUID algorithm such as one described in RFC4122.  -If you do not
>   specify an ID, it will be automatically generated by the server.